# I can not solve this problem. When I compile ,the compiler gives me an error because of free func

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void copyint(char *i,char** temp);
int main()
{
    char* a="00313";
    char* temp;
    int inte;
    temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    copyint(a,&temp);

    inte=atoi(temp);
    printf("%s\n",temp);
    system("PAUSE");
    free(temp);
}

void copyint(char *i,char** temp)
{
    *temp=i;
}
```

Comment: When asking about compiler errors, always add the __exact error message__ and __indicate the line__ it points to. You might also want to add which compiler (and version thereof) you're using.

Comment: Please reformat the question. Also if you can solve the problem, why are you asking here? Did you mean you "can't" solve the problem?

Comment: What's mistake? What compiler? What environment?

Comment: The OP code is probably wrong, but I don't get compiler errors. I tried with gcc version 4.5.0 and -Wall -pedantic flags.

Comment: To all what's been said already, I've to point out this one: In C one doesn't typecast void* pointers into target pointer types, you just assign them. The allocation should read temp=malloc(...); If the compiler complains you're either compiling as C++, or your compiler doesn't comply to ANSI C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no question so point what is wrong on the first sight:
- copyint copies single char into pointed memory.
so what is being done: temp value is '0', random, random....

'0',random random is parsed by atoi - undefined since we don't know what under this pointer resides.
and then it's printed out...

use `strlen malloc strcpy` sequence instead

Edit: it doesn't compile since you pass a (char*) into function which accepts (char). (`copyint(a,&temp);`)

Comment: Why is improperly indented code better than what's shown in the question?

Comment: Because before edit it wasn't caught with `code` block and was very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is bugged.

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

allocates one byte to temp.

```
copyint(a, &temp);
```

passes the ADDRESS of "temp". "temp" then gets overwritten so it no longer points to the allocated memory. Hence it cannot be freed.

Secondly, the first parameter to copyint is a `char` but you are passing a `char *`. Lastly, what on earth are you doing with `atoi()`?

I think you need to find out what `copyint()` actually does. What are you trying to do anyway?
of

Answer (score 0):

You are allocationg memory for 1 char, but copying 4 bytes to that pointer in copyint function.

Comment: No, worse. he is allocating memory, then modifying the pointer with the `copyint` function, then freeing a memory zone that correspond to a string literal.

Comment: I don't think the memory zone corresponds to a string literal. I think copyint here just copies one byte, so only one byte of the address gets corrupted. How come so many answerers failed to spot that temp is a pointer and getting corrupted?

Answer (score -1):

Even if the question is not so clear, I believe that including *malloc.h* will solve the problem, at least if you're using a VC compiler.
HTH